# Вопрос по тестовому задание из книги по С

Tags: c

Читаю книгу по С, там есть такой пример и тестовое задание к нему:

```
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0) /* record sign */
        n = -n; /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do { /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0'; /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0); /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

> 3-4. бла-бла-бла ... itoa не сможет
> обработать наибольшее отрицательное
> число, равное
> `-(2^wordsize-1)`.
> Объясните, почему так происходит.

У меня пока очень туго с представлением реально происходящих процессов. Такое число не может быть обработано, потому что (грубо говоря) для него нет соответствующего положительного и INT_MAX (или аналог, если делать для какого-нибудь long) будет на единицу меньше того, что должно быть получено в результате `n = -n`? Если так, что в этот момент запишется в переменную n? 0x0...01? 0xF0...0? Просто INT_MAX? Это будет зависеть от конкретной машины?

Comment: Лапша на ухи. Не сможет обработать -(2^wordsize) (для двухбайтных целых), а -(2^wordsize-1) -- пожалуйста. Поскольку INT_MAX как раз и будет 2^wordsize-1
(но всё это для 16-бит платформ, если wordsize==16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz), **а вот и не лапша...**

Проверьте:

```
  if (INT_MIN == -INT_MIN)
    puts("xaxa");
```

(в gcc при компиляции warning насчет переполнения).

А дальше сразу вываливаемся из `do ... while()`, поскольку частное будет отрицательным.

--

Функция легко исправляется проверкой на INT_MIN после `if ((sign = n) < 0)`. В этом случае первую цифру (и первое деление на 10) вычисляем через `unsigned`

```
  ...
  i = 0;
  if (n == INT_MIN) { // лучше с константами. Компилятор может просто все подставить
    s[i++] = (unsigned)INT_MIN % 10 + '0';
    n = (unsigned)INT_MIN / 10;
  }
```

Далее все оставим.

--

[[@Fike](/users/16095/fike)](/users/16095/fike), да это из-за переполнения (т.е. для него нет положительного).

**UPDATE**

Пожалуй, лучше все начало `itoa()` заменить на

```
  int i = 0, sign;

  if ((sign = n) < 0) /* record sign */
    if (n == INT_MIN) { 
      s[i++] = (unsigned)INT_MIN % 10 + '0';
      n = (unsigned)INT_MIN / 10;
    }
    else 
      n = -n; /* make n positive */

  do { 
    ...
```

Comment: @avp

    int main() {
         int n = 0x80000001;
         char s[20]; 
         itoa(n, s);
         printf("%s\n", s);
         return 0;
    }

    alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ./a.out
    -2147483647

При `int n = 0x80000000;` получаем обещанный облом

Возможно я должен был заострить внимание на том, что INT_MIN -- это не -(2^wordsize-1), а -(2^wordsize)

Comment: Мало-мало наврал, но с подачи ТС. INT_MIN = -(2^(n-1)) (для 16бит -- -(2:(wordsize-1)) ). Он скобочку не поставил, а я не заметил